# Is there a way to have F12 tools print out what function is being run?

Tags: javascript, css, performance

I've inherited a client-side js/css/html code base that does way too much.  It Chrome/Firefox/Edge, it's reasonably quick, but in IE11 - it's unusable.  Since it does a massive amount of stuff, it's difficult to follow along. There tons of things running on timer, events on mousemove, script deferals, endless layout events when nothing is happening on screen, various modules loading every JavaScript framework from the last 10 years, you name it.

Is there anyway to get the F12 tools in browsers to dump out to the console what function it is currently running?

P.S. I've recorded performance, but it didn't reveal a whole lot.

Comment: have you tried using google chrome's performance tab then looking at the call tree as described here https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/12/devtools-javascript-cpu-profile-migration

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/js-execution

Comment: Do not debug in IE

Comment: @Amit What would you suggest instead of debugging in IE?  That's where the problem is.

Comment: @slackOverflow That's essentially the problem.  If I record the CPU profile in Chrome, everything looks reasonable.  The problem is in IE and recording it there doesn't reveal the culprit.

Comment: Why is it unusable in ie. Does the screen hang due to network or elements render again and again, not clickable at all. Ui may do tons of stuff but does it hamper user experience. Right now, what i am getting is that you may have to bundle and minify few js and css and instead of letting it load as per script mechanism, you may have to load them declaratively.

Answer (score 1):

You could try out recording your own [performance marks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/mark) to narrow bottlenecks and work out from there.